# Can voltage across an inductor change instantly?

Tags: voltage, inductor

If current is passed through an inductor, there will be a voltage across it. If that current source is disconnected, the voltage across it reverses. Does this happen instantly?

Comment: *If current is passed through an inductor, there will be a voltage across it.* Not if that current is **constant** (I'm ignoring the inductor's DC-series resistance) and the inductor is "charged" meaning the magnetic field has reached its final value. Inductors want to keep the **current** constant, if you interrupt the current the magnetic field will start to collapse immediately causing the current in the inductor to want to go in the reversed direction, there is no path for that current (you interrupted it) so the voltage will rise immediately.

Comment: @FakeMoustache good point! Wasn't thinking.

Comment: FakeMustache pointed out the movement of current. In addition to that, think about V=I.R. *I* does not drop to zero instantly, *R* goes infinity; so V goes infinity (in theory) and that is what we called spike.